# str not callable sendto python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, encryption

attempting message encryption with a basic client to host connection 
client code:

```
import socket
import datetime
import time

import threading

tLock = threading.Lock()
shutdown = False

def receving(name, sock):
    while not shutdown:
        try:
            tLock.acquire()
            while True:
                data, addr = socket.recvfrom(1024)
                print (str(data))
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            tLock.release()

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 0

server = ('127.0.0.1',5000)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.setblocking(0)

rT = threading.Thread(target=receving, args=("RecvThread",s))
rT.start()

alias = input("Name: ")
IP=int(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()).replace(".","5"))
time=(int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")))
qw=(int(str((time)+(IP))))
a=int("934")
b=int("346")
c=int("926")
d=int("9522")
e=int("7334")
f=int("5856")
g=int("2432")
h=int("2027")
i=int("7024")
j=int("828")
k=int("798")
m=int("593")
n=int("662")
l=int("5950")
o=int("357")
p=int("506")
q=int("237")
r=int("98")
s=int("372")
t=int("636")
u=int("553")
v=int("255")
w=int("298")
x=int("8822")
y=int("458")
z=int("657")
space=("633")
msg=input("")
msg=msg.replace("a",(str(a)))
msg=msg.replace("b",(str(b)))
msg=msg.replace("c",(str(c)))
msg=msg.replace("d",(str(d)))
msg=msg.replace("e",(str(e)))
msg=msg.replace("f",(str(f)))
msg=msg.replace("g",(str(g)))
msg=msg.replace("h",(str(h)))
msg=msg.replace("i",(str(i)))
msg=msg.replace("j",(str(j)))
msg=msg.replace("k",(str(k)))
msg=msg.replace("m",(str(m)))
msg=msg.replace("n",(str(n)))
msg=msg.replace("l",(str(l)))
msg=msg.replace("o",(str(o)))
msg=msg.replace("p",(str(p)))
msg=msg.replace("q",(str(q)))
msg=msg.replace("r",(str(r)))
msg=msg.replace("s",(str(s)))
msg=msg.replace("t",(str(t)))
msg=msg.replace("u",(str(u)))
msg=msg.replace("v",(str(v)))
msg=msg.replace("w",(str(w)))
msg=msg.replace("x",(str(x)))
msg=msg.replace("y",(str(y)))
msg=msg.replace("z",(str(z)))
msg=msg.replace(" ",(str(space)))
print(msg)
msg=int(msg)
msg=int(msg)*(qw)
print(msg)
fileb=open("key.txt","w")
filec=fileb.write(str(qw))
fileb.close()
file=open("msg decrypt.txt","w")
filea=file.write(str(msg))
file.close()
msg=(str(e)(msg))
print(IP)
print(qw)
if msg != 'q':
    if msg != '':
        s.sendto(alias.encode() + ": ".encode() + (str(msg).encode)(), server)
tLock.acquire()
msg = input(alias + "-> ")
tLock.release()

shudown = True
rT.join()
s.close()
```

host code:

```
import socket
import time

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5000

clients = []

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.setblocking(0)

quitting = False
print ("Server Started.")
while not quitting:
    try:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        if "Quit" in str(data):
            quitting = True
        if addr not in clients:
            clients.append(addr)

        print (time.ctime(time.time()) + str(addr) + ": :" + str(data))
        for client in clients:
            s.sendto(data, client)
    except:
        pass
s.close()
```

Im struggling as my poor excuse of a encryption is mostly numbers so therefore when im sending using the sendto function only uses str`s or so I think? 
either way I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\client 2.py", line 103, in <module>
    msg=(str(e)(msg))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Parens, parens, parens everywhere

Comment: What is the purpose of this line `msg=(str(e)(msg))`? Also an error in the client's `receiving()` function - it should be `sock.recvfrom(1024)`, not `socket.recvfrom()`. This error is hidden by the bare `except` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `msg` is an index you should write :

```
msg = str(e)[msg]
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\client 2.py", line 103, in <module>
    msg = str(e)[msg]
IndexError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer

Comment: `msg = str(e)[msg] if msg < len(str(e)) else str(e)[0]`

Comment: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sendto'

Comment: File "H:\client 2.py", line 107, in <module>
    s.sendto(alias.encode() + ": ".encode() + (str(msg).encode)(), server)

Comment: You wrote `s = int("372")` and integer has no method sendto ... Are you sure of what you are doing ?

Comment: nope honestly this is just a concept I`m only 16 and know the very basics

Comment: Use another name for your socket, for example `sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)`, then replace `s.sendto(data, client)` by `sock.sendto(data, client)`

Comment: wow im dumb I only just realised I have 2 variable`s with the same name

Comment: one problem while using str(e) '(e)' corresponds to the variable

Comment: Yes, in your code code `e` comes from `e=int("7334")`